# How to send a read receipt of a push notification to Amazon Pinpoint on Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, aws-pinpoint

Hello my dear friends,

I'm trying to send back a read receipt for push notifications to Amazon's Pinpoint, so I can know when users have read a push notification previously sent to my apps. On iOS, in Swift, that's possible by using the following piece of code:

```
var pinpoint: AWSPinpoint?

AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
pinpoint = AWSPinpoint(configuration: AWSPinpointConfiguration.defaultPinpointConfiguration(launchOptions: launchOptions))

AWSDDLog.add(AWSDDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)
AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .info
```

I found something related to that in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/aws-mobile-dg.pdf), but it's not quite clear on how to send it back on Android. They create some sort of Login view, which is not exactly what I want.

My question is: how do I send that response - a read receipt to my push notification - back to Pinpoint on **Android**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Pinpoint mobile SDK and it is set up properly this receipt is supposed to be generated automatically by the SDK itself.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how we can access these read receipts?